# Create rectangle shapefile from 4 coordinate pairs

Tags: qgis, python, polygon, coordinates

I have four coordinate pairs that I am trying to convert into a rectangle polygon by connecting them.

NW:-97.22082767, 46.8326489

NE:-97.21021166, 46.83248334

SW:-97.22096573, 46.82846637

SE:-97.21035054, 46.82830084

I tried the following code, but the AOI doesn't show up in QGIS/doesn't seem to be projected right either. Any suggestions for how to fix this code to create a rectangle polygon from these four points?

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon


# function to return polygon
def bbox(vec):
    long0, lat0, lat1, long1 = vec[0], vec[1], vec[2], vec[3]
    return Polygon([[long0, lat0], # bottom left
                    [long0,lat1], # top left
                    [long1,lat1], # top right
                    [long1, lat0]]) # bottom right


def extentPolygon(df):
    return(
        pd.DataFrame({'geometry' : df[['ext_min_x','ext_min_y','ext_max_y','ext_max_x']].apply(bbox, axis = 1)})
    )


df = pd.DataFrame({'ext_min_x' : [-97.22096573, 46.82846637], 'ext_max_x' : [-97.22082767, 46.8326489],
                    'ext_min_y' : [-97.21021166, 46.83248334],  'ext_max_y' : [-97.21035054, 46.82830084]})
df = extentPolygon(df)

df_gp = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df)
df_gp.crs= 'epsg:4326'
df_gp.to_file('dataframe.shp', driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

Comment: what result do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your answer:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
# Make a list of latitudes and longitudes of the four points
# the fifth point is the first point to make last edge of polygon go back to start
lat_point_list = [46.82846637, 46.8326489, 46.83248334, 46.82830084, 46.82846637]
lon_point_list = [-97.22096573, -97.22082767, -97.21021166, -97.21035054, -97.22096573]

# Either keep the geometry based on the four input points
polygon_geometry = Polygon(zip(lon_point_list, lat_point_list))
# Or make sure to get a rectangle by using the bounding box of the initial polygon
# polygon_geometry.bounds[0] = xmin of bounding box around polygon
# polygon_geometry.bounds[1] = ymin of bounding box around polygon
# polygon_geometry.bounds[2] = xmax of bounding box around polygon
# polygon_geometry.bounds[3] = ymax of bounding box around polygon
rectangle_polygon_geometry = Polygon([[polygon_geometry.bounds[0], polygon_geometry.bounds[1]],
                                      [polygon_geometry.bounds[2], polygon_geometry.bounds[1]],
                                      [polygon_geometry.bounds[2], polygon_geometry.bounds[3]],
                                      [polygon_geometry.bounds[0], polygon_geometry.bounds[3]],
                                      [polygon_geometry.bounds[0], polygon_geometry.bounds[1]]])
crs = 'epsg:4326'
polygon = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs=crs, geometry=[rectangle_polygon_geometry])
polygon.to_file('dataframe.shp', driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

Result seemed okay in QGIS and folium.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a self intersecting = invalid, polygon:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

c =  {'NW': [-97.22082767, 46.8326489],
      'NE': [-97.21021166, 46.83248334],
      'SW': [-97.22096573, 46.82846637],
      'SE': [-97.21035054, 46.82830084]}


poly1 = Polygon([c['NW'], c['NE'], c['SW'], c['SE']])
poly2 = Polygon([c['NW'], c['NE'], c['SE'], c['SW']])

#poly1.is_valid
#False

#poly2.is_valid
#True
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adjusting @Davma 's answer, as the coordinates were slightly off. Here is what I ended up using:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

# Or make sure to get a rectangle by using the bounding box of the initial polygon
rectangle_polygon_geometry = Polygon([[-97.22096573, 46.82846637],
                                      [-97.22082767, 46.8326489],
                                      [-97.21021166, 46.83248334],
                                      [-97.21035054, 46.82830084],
                                      [-97.22096573, 46.82846637]])
crs = 'epsg:4326'
polygon = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs=crs, geometry=[rectangle_polygon_geometry])
polygon.to_file('dataframe.shp', driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```